# xgboost Predictions from R and Python don't match

Tags: xgboost

Thought maybe somebody here could help us solve a mystery (https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1623):

We are trying to build a xgboost prediction function in R for a model that was trained in Python and the results don't match. See below for an example of how to reproduce.

Fairly new to xgboost, particularly using it across languages, so may be missing something obvious.

**Steps to reproduce:**

(1) Download this model file: http://ml.stat.purdue.edu/hafen/WTKG.model

(2) Run this script in R:

```
library(xgboost)
mod <- xgb.load("WTKG.model")
x <- c(91, 9, 9, NA, NA, 273, 20, 170, NA, NA, 14, 14, 0,
  2, 0.94289404091, 0.94289404091, 0.93087973569, 0.0120143052199997, 0.95490834613,
  0.95490834613, 1, 90, 0.95490834613, 1, 90,
  0.93087973569, 357, -266, 0.93087973569, 357, -266,
  0.95490834613, NA, 0.93087973569, NA, NA, NA)
d <- xgb.DMatrix(matrix(x, nrow = 1), missing = NA)
predict(mod, d)
# [1] 0.6483372
```

(3) Run this script in Python:

```
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb

bst = xgb.Booster({'nthread': 4})
bst.load_model('WTKG.model')
x = [91, 9, 9, np.nan, np.nan, 273, 20, 170, np.nan, np.nan, 14, 14, 0,
  2, 0.94289404091, 0.94289404091, 0.93087973569, 0.0120143052199997, 0.95490834613,
  0.95490834613, 1, 90, 0.95490834613, 1, 90,
  0.93087973569, 357, -266, 0.93087973569, 357, -266,
  0.95490834613, np.nan, 0.93087973569, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
d = xgb.DMatrix(data=[x], missing=np.nan)
bst.predict(d)[0]
# 1.3775804
```

Comment: have you read [this entry](https://www.kaggle.com/c/caterpillar-tube-pricing/forums/t/15885/xgboost-different-between-python-and-r/89194) on kaggle? or [this one](https://www.kaggle.com/c/predicting-red-hat-business-value/forums/t/22743/results-different-with-xgb-in-r-and-python/130490)?

Comment: I checked the github issue you are referring to. Could it be because of difference in xgboost version? The model was built under xgboost 0.6, while the R version used is version 0.4-4.

Comment: @phiver That's a great point. It looks like the CRAN version hasn't been updated in quite a while.

Answer (score 3):

Solution for posterity: In Python, xgboost requires np.array as input. So this line:

```
d = xgb.DMatrix(data=[x], missing=np.nan)
```

should be:

```
d = xgb.DMatrix(data=np.array([x]), missing=np.nan)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can get your answer from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/caterpillar-tube-pricing/forums/t/15885/xgboost-different-between-python-and-r)

Comment: This post shows that if you FIT separately in Python and R you may get different results. But I have one model already trained/fit. The predictions should be the same regardless of how different the fitting procedures are, no?